# Difference between a class(namedtuple) and a namedtuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

What is the difference between `class(namedtuple)` and only `namedtuple`, they look different but in both cases `sensor` seems to be the same thing, and what kind of functionality can be added inside `class Sensor` in `case1`?

```py
from collections import namedtuple
# case 1
class Sensor(namedtuple('Sensor', ['name', 'location', 'version', 'pressure', 'temperature'])):
    pass
sensor = Sensor(name="example", location="warehouse_125", version="1", pressure=128, temperature=10)

# case 2
Sensor = namedtuple('Sensor', ['name', 'location', 'version', 'pressure', 'temperature'])
sensor = Sensor(name="example", location="warehouse_125", version="1", pressure=128, temperature=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that `collections.namedtuple` is a factory function. It *returns* a subclass of a tuple which is gonna be your actual class.

So by doing:

```py
class Sensor(namedtuple('Sensor', ['name', 'location', 'version', 'pressure', 'temperature'])):
    pass
```

You're subclassing this newly created namedtuple class. Just like:

```py
class Sensor(<another_class>):
    pass
```

> what kind of function/code can be added inside class Sensor in case1?

This is extending/subclassing another class, you can add whatever you want. But in "case 2", `Sensor` is only a name/symbol which is bound to the actual namedtuple class.

The inheritance chain would be:

```
#case 1
object > tuple > namedtuple class(without attached symbol) > Sensor

#case 2
object > tuple > namedtuple class(Sensor)
```

> but can you give some example that I can add inside class `Sensor`? to
> show there is an use case or advantage of using class `Sensor`?

For example you can have a method call `.store()` which add this namedtuple object to a database. Or maybe you can have a property which says the weather in the location of the sensor is cold or hot?

```py
from collections import namedtuple


class Sensor(namedtuple("Sensor", ["name", "location", "temperature"])):
    def store(self):
        """Add this object to the DataBase"""
        print("Adding to the database...")
        # Make a connection to the database
        # INSERT INTO ....

    @property
    def weather(self):
        if self.temperature > 30:
            return "Hot"
        if 10 < self.temperature <= 30:
            return "Moderate"
        if self.temperature <= 10:
            return "Cold"


sensor_1 = Sensor("A1", "warehouse125", 20)
sensor_1.store()
print(f"The weather is {sensor_1.weather}")
```

These `.store()` and `.weather` were not in `namedtuple` class. You *extend* it and give them extra functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the difference between, but can you give some example that I can add insisde `class Sensor`? to show there is an use case or advantage of using `class Sensor`, thank you so much

Comment: @Tung Answer updated. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Can I ask one last question, what is the difference(pros and cons) between the example and writing the same thing but in a regular class with `def __init__(self, name, location, temperature)`?

Comment: @Tung By inheriting from NamedTuple, your underlying structure is a *tuple*, which is very lightweight. If you ignore inheriting from namedtuple class, and store those attributes in instance's dictionary, it would become much larger in size. Also you're getting all functionalities that the tuple class has implemented for free. For example accessing by index, or equality testing with attributes and etc.

Comment: clear explaination, I think you could add these to the answer, thanks.